# Django - Check if a variable set exists in the Database and process it if it does?

Tags: python, django, database

So I have a Django App, where a CSV-File can be uploaded. My CSV-File has 9 columns that can be divided into two "datasets" where the first 5 columns need to be handled as one information and the other 4 need to be handled as another information. I cannot put the first 5 in one cell and the other ones in another cell. I would like to check whether or not the first dataset exists and if it does, process it. The same applies to the other dataset. And if both datasets do not exist already it should just update the Database with get_or_create.

Here is my `views.py` idea

```
    def import_csv(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        with open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/djangoexcel/b.csv') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                var = CSV_File4.objects.filter(
                    attr1=row[0], attr2=row[1], attr3=row[2], attr4=row[3], attr5=row[4],
                )
                if var.exists():
                    TemplateResponse(request, "documents/replace_entry.html", {'var' : var})
                else:
                    for row in reader:
                        switch = CSV_File4.objects.filter(
                            attr6=row[5], attr7=row[6], attr8=row[7], attr9=row[8]
                        )
                        if var2.exists():
                            TemplateResponse(request, "documents/replace_entry.html", {'var2' : var2})
                        else:
                            for row in reader:
                                _, p = CSV_File4.objects.get_or_create(
                                    attr1=row[0], attr2=row[1], attr3=row[2], attr4=row[3], attr5=row[4],
                                    attr6=row[5], attr7=row[6], attr8=row[7], attr9=row[8]
                                )


            return redirect('documents:index')
    form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
        request, "documents/csv_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```

It should look something like this. How can I make this work. It was just an idea with filter() and exists() but is there a Python way to do something like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are trying to recursively iterate through `reader` three times. That's not possible, because it is an `Iterator`, not a `list`. Anyway, you only need to do it once and then work on that particular line, before skipping to the next.

```
def import_csv(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        with open('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/djangoexcel/b.csv') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                ds1 = CSV_File4.objects.filter(
                    attr1=row[0], attr2=row[1], attr3=row[2], attr4=row[3], attr5=row[4],
                ).exists()
                ds2 = CSV_File4.objects.filter(
                    attr6=row[5], attr7=row[6], attr8=row[7], attr9=row[8]
                ).exists()

                if ds1:
                    pass  # Process first dataset
                if ds2:
                    pass  # Process second dataset
                if not (ds1 and ds2):
                    _, p = CSV_File4.objects.get_or_create(
                        attr1=row[0], attr2=row[1], attr3=row[2], attr4=row[3], attr5=row[4],
                        attr6=row[5], attr7=row[6], attr8=row[7], attr9=row[8]
                    )

            return redirect('documents:index')

    return render(
        request, "documents/csv_upload.html", {"form": UploadFileForm()}
    )
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. It looks like it does add the row to the DB regardless of the existence of one dataset. I copied one row and only changed ds2. ds1 was the same so it should give a TemplateResponse at this point and use the Template to chek if the entry needs to be replaced(see in my question). But in this case it just added the row. Do you have an idea what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. "Give a TemplateResponse"? What does that do? Render the rows found into a template but not store the result anywhere? How should a template check if anything needs to be replaced?

Comment: Well lets say I changed attr3 in row x and I upload the file to the DB again, it should just upload the file with the changed value. Instead with my current solution it adds the line with the changed attribute to the existing rows. So "all" I need is to update the value in the table (if?) or add a new value. That is the problem I have right now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I see. Are the parts unique? That is, for example when you filter by the attributes in `ds1`, will you get *exactly* 0 or 1 results? Or could it happen that you get more than 1 result? If so, I would suggest you use a proper Primary Key (usually called `id`) for your database table and your CSV file, so that you can uniquely identify rows.

Comment: Well my Sqlite3 DB already adds a unique ID field to the table (I think it is because of Django), so by adding it to my models.py it would be doubled. But your suggestion is something to consider, because if I change a value of a existing row/ID it should ask whether or not the value needs to be updated, and if the number of rows has changed it should give like a message, that the entry already exists (if it already does). I thought about using count() maybe? Sorry this is a project I have to do this way, so this is not my intention.

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you can't add the `id` (yes, its added by Django) to the CSV file? Using `count()` would only work if you can guarantee that no row is ever deleted. Or, as I asked above: you can add a constrained that each value groupd (`ds1` and `ds2`) can be used as a lookup key.  In Django, you can do that [by adding `Meta.unique_together` to the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip. And as for changing a value in row x, the only and best way to do this would be by using the id to see i.e. that there is a changed value in row x and then decide to whether update or cancel?  Because in that case how can I implement the ID into the code above. I would have to check if the row values of id = x still match the values of the new file right? But in that case is filter() and exists() still the right approach or do I have to restructure the whole code?